# What does "!default" mean for a dependency

Tags: javascript, dojo, amd, js-amd

When I look at the source code of the dojo 1.7 amd dependency list, i see the following:

> define(["./_base/kernel", "./has", "./dom", "./on", "./_base/array",
>   "./_base/lang", "./selector/_loader", "./selector/_loader!default"],

The only use of an exclamation mark I know is for plugins, I haven't seen this "!default" before.
I read this page "https://github.com/amdjs/amdjs-api/wiki/AMD" and googled about it, but I did not find any answer.
Can anybody help me with that!
Thanks
Wolfgang

Update:
Thank you, Ates Goral, for your answer.
Now everything is clear to me.
Then, the irritating thing for me with this special case was, that "./selector/_loader" occurs twice in the above line, one time without parameters and the next time with a parameter. I saw people writing "dojo/domReady!", so I thought it was mandatory to write an exclamation mark for a plugin, even without parameters. Now I have learned that plugins don't need an "!" and I will write "dojo/domReady".

Another Update:
Today I found the following interesting statement (main.js of https://github.com/csnover/dojo-boilerplate):

> The “!” after the module name indicates you want to use special plugin functionality; if you were to require just “dojo/domReady”, it would load that module just like any 
>   other module, without any of the special plugin functionality.

I don't know if this statement is correct. It it is correct, then "./selector/_loader" would have some kind of hybrid functionality?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

http://livedocs.dojotoolkit.org/loader/amd

> When a module identifier passed to require or define contains an "!",
>   the loader splits the string in two at the exclamation point. The
>   string to the left of "!" is treated like a normal module ID and is
>   used as the identifier for the desired plugin; the string to the right
>   of "!" is passed to the plugin for processing.

In your case, "default" is being passed to the plugin.

Comment: Or in other words, the real question should be "what does `./selector/_loader` mean"?

Comment: @missingno It's a plugin that determines which selector engine to use.